# Advantage to using the this keyword with selectedIndex?

Tags: javascript, this, selectedindex

Is there any advantage to this:

```
document.getElementById('mySelectBox').options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

over this:

```
document.getElementById('mySelectBox').options[selectedIndex].value
```

Just curious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you don't use `this`, you will be accessing a variable instead of the property in the object.

Javascript isn't object oriented, so you are never in the scope of an object, where you could access properties without specifying which object they belong to.

Anyway, if `this` refers to the element, just use:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: Thanks.  What confused me is that placing that little snippet without this this keyword into <select onchange="window.open(document.getElementById('mySelectBox').options[selectedIndex].value)" seemed to work in Firefox.  I wonder if that's just because I was using the event attribute.

Comment: @JulianJohannesen: The browser might copy some element properties and expose them as local variables in the scope of the event handler.

Comment: I think you may have answered a separate question that I just posted about this!